# While working on Robot framework , encountered an Import error message when attempting to add Resource in Setting Section?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, robotframework

[image]

In Robot Framework , I have segregated the details into Page objects, keywords and scripts.

After adding keywords in PO, I wanted to add details in Keywords. Here, in Settings section while I give the following details:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Resource    Resources/PO/Sign-in.robot
```

I even tried using absolute path by referencing ../ at the beginning. Still, system is unable to recognize it and throwing an error message "Import File Not Found".

What Should I be doing? Please, let me know?

Answer (score 1):

First, you show in the screenshot, the use of a variable `${Resources}`, it would be normal for the IDE to not recognize that value for a path. Even so, running the test case may work as expected.

Second, if you want to use the relative path, then the correct value should be:

```
Resource    ../PO/Sign-in.robot
```

Comment: Also, use `${/}` as the path separator.